# Javascript async example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

i'm experimenting with es6 promises and chaining them and don't understand why my example doesn't work.

i want to chain printInterval() and setInterval() multiple times and expect _interval to decrease like this:

- waited 3000ms to display this message
- setting interval to  2000
- waited 2000ms to display this message
- setting interval to  1000
- waited 1000ms to display this message
- setting interval to  500
- waited 500ms to display this message

but i get the following:

- waited 3000ms to display this message
- setting interval to  2000
- setting interval to  1000
- setting interval to  500
- waited 500ms to display this message
- waited 500ms to display this message
- waited 500ms to display this message

.

```
function printInterval() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('waited ' + _interval + 'ms to display this message')
            resolve(_interval);
        }, _interval)
    })
}

function setInterval(interval){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('setting interval to ', interval)
            _interval = interval;
            resolve(_interval);
        }, 0);
    })
}

var _interval = 3000;

printInterval()
.then(function(){setInterval(2000)})
.then(function(){printInterval()})
.then(function(){setInterval(1000)})
.then(function(){printInterval()})
.then(function(){setInterval(500)})
.then(function(){printInterval()});
```

thank you!

Comment: Tip: Don't overwrite the global `setInterval` function! (unrelated to your problem)

Comment: What's this horrible global `_interval` variable? You really ought to keep that local to your functions.

Comment: yes you are right, but it was just a test to understand promise-chaining and i *really wanted** to use that global variable in that experimental case. could you explain your first tip please? i figured out, that the setTimeout in the setInterval function can be left out. i first thought that this could be needed to "make it async", but i was wrong. what do you mean with "don't overwrite **global** setInterval"? thank you!

Comment: Just saying that [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) is a native method and you should choose a different name for yours to not confuse everyone.

Comment: okay, understood. just a test-case :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should `return` those functions not just call them:

```
printInterval()
.then(function(){return setInterval(2000)})
.then(function(){return printInterval()})
.then(function(){return setInterval(1000)})
.then(function(){return printInterval()})
.then(function(){return setInterval(500)})
.then(function(){return printInterval()});
```

Comment: Why no `return` for the last one?

Comment: No one to catch that last promise :)

Comment: we've answered at the same time :) thank you for your solution, that's what i've found out, too!

Comment: @kaaposc: What do you think `then` does if not "catch" the returned promises? You are destroying chaining.